# Edit farmers stills here

Tags: feature-request, support

#### Disclaimer

This question is about a known practice of some users that keep making irrelevant edits on questions/answers to get badges or rep, I guess. I'm aware that some similar questions have been asked here before, but I haven't found any of these that mention:

- How to take an action or report obvious edit farming
- High reputation users have their edits reviewed

#### Question

For a month now I've noticed *that guy* on SO editing tags faster than Jon Skeet answers a question. I've seen too minor edits by him from `C#` to `CSS` questions. I've also seen irrelevant edits like adding [directory-structure](/questions/tagged/directory-structure) in questions that contain terms like, "I've put my files in that folder." Aren't these edits reviewed? He has about 30k rep on SO; does that bypass edit reviews?

Can we do something about it?
Since the review system doesn't work 100%, could we have a flag system for edits? Even comments can be flagged; why not edits?

Comment: Hrm, why didn't you ask this on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: Users with 2K reputation have full edit privilege, so yes, those edits are not reviewed. Speaking of tags, what feature are you requesting here? Also, did you mean to post this on Meta.SO, by any chance?

Comment: @animuson This happened there but the question is more about the Q&A engine itself. The user privileges, how the review system works, this is the same on all SE sites.

Comment: Well, does the edit make the posts substantially better?

Comment: @cvsguimaraes This really doesnt happen a lot on most sites. If it does, it gets discussed and resolved on the per-site-metas, which seems to be the appropriate path here. If you were suggesting a change or an improvement to the system (*which you aren't*), then this may have been relevant to MSE.

Comment: @Undo No, sometimes wrong tags are added.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills question updated about the feature request

Comment: As far as I understand, this site is for questions that are **not** specific to one site. You can still discuss the network or the Q&A software on per-site metas if the premise of your question is site-specific. I agree with the rest that this is more suited to MSO.

Comment: Probably will be as long as the farming is still good... ;)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Are you able to migrate this question?

Comment: Can't do, as I'm not a moderator here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a user gets to 2k reputation, they can edit without peer review. They no longer get rep bonuses, so no complaining about that. Because of the lack of review, they are allowed to make minor edits (without annoying 3 reviewers over a simple typo or tagging) that would otherwise be rejected.

If you don't like the edit, you can:

- Roll it back (requires 2k rep)
- Edit it out (your edit will be peer reviewed, so editing out an edit is only for substantial edits)
- Ignore it (yeah, I said it). If it's a minor edit that isn't too bad (invalid, vandalism, etc.) you don't really need to bother doing anything about it.
- If there are a bunch of bad edits, flag a post as "other" so a moderator can investigate.

Yes, there are "edit flags". Just flag the post for moderator attention. Only do this if there is something **serious**, like an edit war.